# Change the field of all objects of the class

Tags: java

I have a class with the boolean field and I want field of only one object to be true at the same time.

I tried to set field of all objects with static method but i could not reach non-static field from static method.(i wasn't aware of logic behind static)

```
    public class ToggleBox
{
   private boolean  selected;

    public ToogleBox()
    {
        selected=false;
    }

    public setOnlyTrue()
    {
        setAllFalse();
        selected=true;
    }
    private static setAllFalse()
    {
        this.selected=false;
    }

}
```

Is there any trick to do this or should i iterate over all objects of class to change all the fields?

Comment: Share some code, like class definition please

Comment: You could add a static field that is the object that is currently set to true and get rid of the boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick I could think of is having a static member that holds the reference of the one instance that has a true property:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static MyClass trueObject = null;

    public void setProperty(boolean value) {
        if (value) {
            trueObject = this;
        } else {
            trueObject = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean getProperty() {
        return trueObject == this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you requirement when you want to create an instance with `true`and a `true` has already been created

A. set ALL the others to false and the new one to true

```
public class ToggleBox {

    private static List<ToggleBox> listAll = new ArrayList<>();

    private boolean selected;

    public ToggleBox(boolean bool) {
        if (bool)                          // if require true
            for (ToggleBox mo : listAll)
                mo.setSelected(false);     // set all other to false

        listAll.add(this);
        this.selected = bool;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean bool) { this.selected = bool; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {  return selected + "";  }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        ToggleBox m1 = new ToggleBox(true);
        ToggleBox m2 = new ToggleBox(false);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listAll.toArray()));  // [true, false]
        ToggleBox m3 = new ToggleBox(true);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listAll.toArray()));  // [false, false,true]
    }

}
```

B. refuse to set the new one to true

```
public class ToggleBox {

    private static boolean alreadyTrue = false;

    private static List<ToggleBox> listAll = new ArrayList<>();

    private boolean selected;

    public ToggleBox(boolean bool) {
        if (bool) {                    // if require true
            if (alreadyTrue)           // if there is already one
                bool = false;          // it will be false
            else                       // else
                alreadyTrue = true;    // it's st to true, and remember it
        }

        this.selected = bool;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {  return selected + "";  }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        ToggleBox m1 = new ToggleBox(true);
        ToggleBox m2 = new ToggleBox(false);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listAll.toArray()));  // [true, false]
        ToggleBox m3 = new ToggleBox(true);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listAll.toArray()));  // [true, false, false]
    }

}
```